# <th:block th:each> is not retrieving data required? Table shows blank

Tags: html, spring-boot, jsp, controller, thymeleaf

This is my JSP file

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>Todo's for ${name}</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Your ToDo's</h1>
            <table>
                <caption>Your Todo's are as follows:</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Target Date</th>
                        <th>Is it completed?</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <th:block th:each="todo : ${todos}">
                        <tr>
                            <td th:text="${todo.desc}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${todo.targetDate}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${todo.done}"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </th:block>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                <br/>
                <a href="/add-todos">Add Todo</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is my TodoService.java file

```
package com.example.springboot.demo.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.in28minutes.springboot.web.model.Todo;

@Service
public class TodoService {
    private static List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
    private static int todoCount = 3;

    static {
        todos.add(new Todo(1, "Prakriti", "Learn Spring MVC", new Date(),
                false));
        todos.add(new Todo(2, "Prakriti", "Learn Struts", new Date(), false));
        todos.add(new Todo(3, "Prakriti", "Learn Hibernate", new Date(),
                false));
    }

    public List<Todo> retrieveTodos(String user) {
        List<Todo> filteredTodos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        for (Todo todo : todos) {
            if (todo.getUser().equals(user)) {
                filteredTodos.add(todo);
            }
        }
        return filteredTodos;
    }

    public void addTodo(String name, String desc, Date targetDate,
            boolean isDone) {
        todos.add(new Todo(++todoCount, name, desc, targetDate, isDone));
    }

    public void deleteTodo(int id) {
        Iterator<Todo> iterator = todos.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Todo todo = iterator.next();
            if (todo.getId() == id) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have three values in the table but it doesn't retrieve them, can't understand why I have used the thymeleaf block properly only. Below is my TodoController.java file.

```
package com.example.springboot.demo.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.example.springboot.demo.service.LoginService;
import com.example.springboot.demo.service.TodoService;


@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class TodoController {
    @Autowired
    TodoService service;

@RequestMapping(value="/list-todos", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showTodosList(ModelMap model) {
    String name=(String)model.get("name");
    model.put("todos",service.retrieveTodos(name));
    return "list-todos";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add-todos", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showaddTodoPage(ModelMap model) {
    return "add-todos";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add-todos", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTodos(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String desc) {
    service.addTodo((String)model.get("name"), desc, new Date(), false);
    return "redirect:/list-todos";
}
}
```

This is my Todo.java

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Todo {
    private int id;
    private String user;
    private String desc;
    private Date targetDate;
    private boolean isDone;

    public Todo(int id, String user, String desc, Date targetDate,
            boolean isDone) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Date getTargetDate() {
        return targetDate;
    }

    public void setTargetDate(Date targetDate) {
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean isDone) {
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Todo other = (Todo) obj;
        if (id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Todo [id=%s, user=%s, desc=%s, targetDate=%s, isDone=%s]", id,
                user, desc, targetDate, isDone);
    }

}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Please let me know what's needed to be done for the values to be displayed in the table.

Comment: When you view the source in the browser, is your Thymeleaf being interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
<tr th:each="todo : ${todos}">
    <td th:text="${todo.desc}"></td>
    <td th:text="${todo.targetDate}"></td>
    <td th:text="${todo.done}"></td>
</tr>
```